# Sniffing trunked IAX2 traffic

Tags: asterisk, voip, wireshark, rtp, sniffing

Is there any way to sniff trunked IAX2 trafic. I make search in google but it's all about sip and rtp.

I make test with wireshark but "Telephony tools" doesn't work correctly with IAX2 as you see in the picture below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE7oU.png]

Answer (score -1):

Trunkes IAX traffic usually encrypted.

So no, no way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Arheops , but I don't set any security configurations for IAX, just the minimum required settings for truncked connexion!

Comment: You see sip becuase it is text protocol. IAX is BINARY protocol, all data including rtp payload go directly via one port/connection.

Comment: Thanks Arheops for those informations, you help me !